# Фильтрация таблицы по столбцам в Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

решил перевести свой проектик с yii2 на джанго (новичек), и столкнулся с маленькой задачкой.
В джанго listview выводится с сортировкой по столбцам, но никак не могу найти опцию чтобы добавить еще и фильтр по столбцам.

[image: в yii2, listview из коробки]
*в yii2, listview из коробки если его сгенерить через gii*

может кто по рекомендует библиотеку, или связку как подобное реализовать, фильтр столбцов в таблице, и если возможно подвязать autocomplete к этому

Comment: Можно использовать `search_fields` атрибут ModelAdmin, чтобы задать список полей, по которым вы хотите вести поиск. Но это будет одна единая строка поиска сверху. Можете попробовать какие-нибудь кастомные решения наподобие https://github.com/shinneider/django-admin-search

Comment: @Александр по-моему тут речь идет не про админку джанги

Comment: `django-rest-framework` подойдет для `autocomplete` и вернет данные в нужно формате. Фильтрация... Можно подкрутить `django-filters`, или использовать его же с `django-rest-framework`. В первом случае передавать параметры фильтрации в GET запросе, во втором тоже, но рендерить таблицу в JS исходя из полученных данных

Comment: Простите, нужно для пользовательского интерфейса, search_fields для админки более чем достаточно.